# Nginx mod_rewrite $request_uri manipulation

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx

I would like to do some redirects but involving the `$args`.

I am trying to to the following:

```
rewrite /aaa?a=1&aa=2 /bbb?b=1&bb=2 permanent;
```

But it does not work. The line below works fine, though

```
rewrite /aaa /bbb permanent;
```

I added those lines to my config file:

```
        proxy_set_header x-request_uri "$request_uri";
        proxy_set_header x-args "$args";
```

And I can see those headers:

```
GET /aaa?a=1&aa=2 HTTP/1.0
Host: www.example.com
x-request_uri: /aaa?a=1&aa=2
x-args: a=1&aa=2
Connection: close
User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.15.3 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
Accept: */*
```

What I am doing wrong? is there a way to accomplish redirect taking full $request_uri in consideration?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer on `irc.freenode.net` `#nginx`:

Mod_rewrite does not match against url-with-args only without, use if or map instead.

I managed to get it working with `if`:

```
if ( $request_uri = '/aaa?a=1&aa=2' ){
    return 301 $scheme://$host/bbb?b=1&bb=2;
}
```

Response header:

```
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.0.15
< Date: Wed, 02 Jul 2014 20:05:34 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 185
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: http://www.example.com/bbb?b=1&bb=2
< x-uri: /aaa?a=1&aa=2
```